# Aplicação SFML estilo Always On Top

Tags: c++, sfml

Eu jogo um jogo de FPS com a classe sniper, porém a sniper não aparece a mira como nas demais armas, o que me atrapalha na hora de mirar o inimigo. Fiz um programa que desenha uma mira na tela. Ele é composto de uma janela transparente que tem as mesmas dimensões da tela. Porém quando executo o jogo eu não consigo interagir com ele pois a aplicação da mira não permite. Como eu posso fazer para que eu consiga jogar normalmente mas com a minha aplicação rodando? Eu quero que a aplicação fique rodando em segundo plano sem atrapalhar o meu uso do computador.

Eis o meu código:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Dwmapi.lib")

int main()
{
    sf::ContextSettings contextSettings;
    contextSettings.antialiasingLevel = 8;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(), "Crosshair", sf::Style::Default, contextSettings);

    SetWindowPos(window.getSystemHandle(), HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    MARGINS margins;
    margins.cxLeftWidth = -1;

    SetWindowLong(window.getSystemHandle(), GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE);
    DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(window.getSystemHandle(), &margins);

    sf::CircleShape crosshair(2.f);
    crosshair.setOrigin(2, 2);
    crosshair.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
    crosshair.setOutlineThickness(3);
    crosshair.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Green);

    sf::Vector2f centerPoint(window.getSize().x / 2.f, window.getSize().y / 2.f);
    crosshair.setPosition(centerPoint);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Transparent);
        window.draw(crosshair);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não é que a sua aplicação impede você de interagir com o jogo, mas o sistema operacional que entende que o jogo está em segundo plano (e, assim, o foco da interação é todo dado à sua aplicação). Você pode tentar fazer a sua aplicação ser do tipo "Stay On Top", e voltar o foco para o jogo, mas como o jogo provavelmente usa OpenGL e vai pra tela cheia esse "truque" provavelmente não vai funcionar. O mais correto seria você fazer algum plugin ou alguma alteração diretamente no código do jogo (ou jogar ele como ele foi projetado para ser jogado).

Comment: De todas as formas, tenho dúvidas se esta pergunta está no escopo do site.